# How to open new tab on ASP C# and focus stay on current page then current page redirect to another page on click button?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, response.redirect

I already tried this code:

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String username = tbxUserName.Text;
        String password = tbxPassword.Text;
        String url = "http://localhost/drupal/login.php?user_name="+username+"&password="+password;

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(), 
            "OpenWindow",
            "var win = window.open('" + url + "','_newtab'); self.focus();", 
            true);

        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
```

That code just redirect to another page, but if I remove `Response.Redirect(url)`, browser open new tab but focus to new tab.

Any body can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should remove `Response.Redirect(url);`, otherwise your code above it is lost. What browser are you using? It's not only you code that controls this behaviour. The browsers have settings for that too. For example, in Internet Explorer 11, go to *Internet Options* and click on the *Tabs* button on the *general* tab. Notice the setting **Always switch to new tabs when they are created**, if it is checked, then it will behave the way you described it. Clear it and see what happens.

Comment: thank's for your answer.. i get it. i think my open tab problem was clear, but if i remove Response.Redirect(url) the current tab isn't go anpther page. my purpose is open another tab and current page change to another page.

Comment: I understand. But you had several problem and when you're in situations like that, it's much easier to tackle them one by one. So we sorted out the first one and we know that you cannot do all what you wanted because you cannot control the browsers. Now with this new info, tell us how exactly you want to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the page in a new window...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onclick", "javascript:window.open( '../../drupal/login.php','_blank','height=600px,width=600px,scrollbars=1');", true);
```

After that redirect to the required page...

```
Response.Redirect(url);
```